# Kendo dropdown change color - white line on the bottom of the container list

Tags: c#, css, kendo-ui

I'm trying to change color and background color of Kendo's dropdown.

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("typeId")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .OptionLabel("Please select an option")
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.Close("someEvent");
    })
    .BindTo(Model.Types)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "ddKendo", style = "width:30%" })
)
```

my css to change color:

```
.ddKendo > .k-dropdown-wrap > .k-input, .k-dropdown, .k-dropdown-wrap, .k-select, .k-list, .k-reset {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}
```

This code almost works. Almost, because dropdown list container has white line on the bottom - you can see it on the screen below:

[image: screen]

I inspected elements and element with white line is:

```
<div class="k-animation-container" style="width: 419px; height: 151px; box-sizing: content-box; overflow: hidden; top: 778px; z-index: 10002; left: 741.797px; padding: 0px; display: none; position: absolute;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="ddContactPage-list" data-role="popup" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; font-size: 14px; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, &quot;Noto Sans&quot;, sans-serif, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;, &quot;Noto Color Emoji&quot;; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px; width: 419.391px; min-width: 419.391px; white-space: normal; height: 100%; transform: translateY(-151px); display: none;">
        <div class="k-list-optionlabel k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="ad46639e-c456-4aca-9681-9a6a56bd49df">Please select an option</div>
        <div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;">
            <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ddContactPage_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
                <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" aria-selected="false" data-offset-index="0">Report a bug</li>
                <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" aria-selected="false" data-offset-index="1">Submit a change request</li>
                <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" aria-selected="false" data-offset-index="2">Submit a project</li>
                <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" aria-selected="false" data-offset-index="3">Other</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="k-nodata" style="display:none">
            <div>No data found.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do this with:

```
.k-animation-container {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
```

but no effect.

Comment: Most likely your rule for the `.k-animation-container` background color is overruled by a more specific selector. Did you inspect the `.k-animation-container` element and see what happened to your styling? If you indeed see that it was overruled by another, more specific rule, make yours more specific than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color and text color of kendo dropdown using the dropdown id list container through following styles,

```
#ddContactPage-list {
    background-color: orange;
    color: red;
}
```

Additionally if you want to update selected item's focused color and hover color, you can apply the following styles,

```
#ddContactPage-list .k-state-focused {
    color: orange;
    background-color: red;
}

#ddContactPage-list .k-state-hover {
    color: blue;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Example dojo is [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/@paulrajj/oPAgupoL) (products dropdown).